# Como hago para que muestre el ID del mismo usuario?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

como hago para que en usuario pueda ver su **idJuego** que guardo en Firebase y asi también que cada usuario vea su propio **idJuego**.

Tengo esta estructura en mi base de datos

[image: SOLO QUIERO QUE MUESTRE EN LA APP EL idJuego]

El código

```
guardarIDff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nombre = nameTextView.getText().toString();
            String email = emailTextView.getText().toString();
            int idJuego =Integer.parseInt(escribirID.getText().toString());

            Map<String, Object> datosUsuario = new HashMap<>();
            datosUsuario.put("nombre", nombre);
            datosUsuario.put("email", email);
            datosUsuario.put("idJuego", idJuego);

            UsuariosG.child("Usuario").push().setValue(datosUsuario);
        }
    });
```

Y esto es lo que estoy usando para llamar el idJuego desde Firebase pero ya no se que mas hacer

```
UsuariosG.child("Usuarios").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

lo podrías realizar de la siguiente manera.

Pero te ayudare para buscarlo de una manera más rápida al usuario

```
UsuariosG.child("Usuarios").orderByChild("email").equalTo("ElCorreoDelUsuario").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            //El usuario Existe
            String idJuego = dataSnapshot.child("idJuego").getValue(String.class);
        }else{
            //El usuario no Existe
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Como hago para que en usuario pueda ver su idJuego que guardo en
>   Firebase y asi también que cada usuario vea su propio idJuego.

Bien, para mostrar a un usuario en particular su ID juego no deberias usar el metodo `push();` , ya que `push();` solo se encarga de crear valores alfanumericos random con un timestamp

Esto tambien depende de tu caso de uso, si no necesitas loguearte para tener informacion en cada usuario y es anonimo vas a tener que guardar esas pushKey que crea el usuario en tu app para luego acceder solo a las que creo, pero si no es ese el caso, te explico lo siguiente.

Esta linea

```
UsuariosG.child("Usuario").push().setValue(datosUsuario);
```

Solo va a generar un ID aleatorio donde se van a guardar los datos, para poder guardarlos bajo cada usuario deberias implementar un metodo de autenticacion con Firebase, ya sea por email o gmail, y despues guardas esos datos debajo de ese usuario

Inicializamos el FirebaseAuth

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Y luego solo lo guardas de la misma forma pero debajo del usuario logueado (Tene en cuenta que si usas un **map**, vas a tener que usar **updateChildren** y no **setValue**, ya que **setValue** te va a reemplazar todos los valores todas las veces que se actualice al menos uno, en cambio **updateChildren** solo va a actuaizar los que se hayan cambiado solamente)

```
UsuariosG.child("Usuario").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(datosUsuario);
```

De esta forma al buscarlo , solo buscaras de cada usuario que esta usando la app de esta forma

```
UsuariosG.child("Usuarios").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           int idJuego = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

Comment: Hola, hice como me sugeriste para guardar los datos con id de Autenticación con Facebook pero para buscar los datos no esta funcionando cuando lo prueba en la app se cierra a los segundos sin mostrar el idJuego, que estaria sucediendo